# Null value in ZXing QR Code Reader decode function

Tags: c#, asp.net, png, qr-code, zxing

My requirement is to scan a QR code from an scanned image. I am using ZXing dll for that. The scanned images are in PNG format and 3 to 5 MB in size. I am using images of a same document. But Zxing decode method scans qr code for one image and fails for other. Could anyone able to fix this.

My code is as below

```
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(path);
    BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader { AutoRotate = true, TryHarder = true };
    Result result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
    string decodedData = result.Text;
```

Comment: Could the issue be that your passing `newBitmap` instead of `bitmap`?

Comment: No I pasted it wrong

Comment: If you're getting an exception you should include it and the stack trace so someone can help you.  Or are you saying it just fails to read the barcode or reads the wrong value?  Could there be an image quality issue?

Comment: result is null no exception. For some image it returns the result

Comment: this website gives the same result as my code. For some images it gives result and for some it doesn't. But both the images are scanned with same document in same scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like issue is with scanned image.